what is the real memory usage of pthread_create
I wrote a simple program of
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void *thread(void *arg) {
  printf("thread() entered with argument '%s'\n", arg);
  pthread_exit((void*)"success");
}

main() {
  pthread_t thid;
  void *ret;

  if (pthread_create(&thid, NULL, thread, (void*)"thread 1") != 0) {
    perror("pthread_create() error");
    exit(1);
  }

  if (pthread_join(thid, &ret) != 0) {
    perror("pthread_create() error");
    exit(3);
  }

  printf("thread exited with '%s'\n", ret);
}

and compiled it into an exacutable called 'thread' on my Ubuntu 24.04. When I run it as
valgrind --tool=massif ./thread

and generate the report I get something like
->04.78% (272B) 0x40145AB: _dl_allocate_tls (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2)
| ->04.78% (272B) 0x48F4606: pthread_create (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6)
|   ->04.78% (272B) 0x10927F: main (in /home/sameer/profile/thread)

which indicates the memory usage of pthread_create to be only 272 bytes. However when I run it as:
valgrind --tool=massif --pages-as-heap=yes ./thread

The report shows
->05.70% (8,392,704B) 0x48E3526: pthread_create (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6)
|   ->05.70% (8,392,704B) 0x10927F: main (in /home/sameer/profile/thread)

which indicates the memory usage to be around 8MB. What is the real memory usage of pthread_create on a system? I am interested in knowing the total memory usage including system overheads etc. valgrind documentation states that simple valgrind (earlier command) may not include memory like mmap etc. It also states that pages-as-heap=yes will show memory usage including system overheads. Does it mean that I can safely assume that 8MB is the system overhead per thread on a typical Ubuntu system?

Wording is important.  What you observe is not that pthread_create() uses one amount of memory or the other.  It is that pthread_create() allocates a certain amount of memory.  What kinds of allocations are reported upon depends on the options presented to valgrind.

It's unlikely that anywhere near the full 8MB you observe is written or read by anything, and it might not even all be backed by any physical resources.  It's unclear what the motivation for the test is, but I'm inclined to think that you need to refine your idea of what you're trying to test before you can determine how best to test it.

It all depends on how the pthread stack is allocated. I haven't looked at the source. If it is allocated using mmap() (most likely) then Massif won't see it in normal operation since it is only looking for calls to malloc(), operator new etc.
When you specify --pages-as-heap=yes then it will be measuring based on mmap() and so it should see all allocations at the lowest possible level outside of the kernel.
You can change the pthread stack size with pthread_attr(). If you aren't doing so the size depends on RLIMIT_STACK. If that is unlimited then your stack size will probably be 2Mb.

In that case why 8MB in valgrind?

Well what is your RLIMIT_STACK?  ulimit -s on Bourne like shells or limit stacksize on C like shells. Valgrind does allocate the main stack but it doesn’t do anything for subsidiary thread stacks.

My ulimit -s is indeed 8MB but it came as default on my Ubuntu 24.04 installation. Is this memory reserved for the multi threaded application or is it just a limit beyond which the application fails, and otherwise available for other applications on the system? I think it does not even show up under RSS but only under VIRT in general.

The way that stacks usually work is that the memory is mapped as two regions, one MAP_STACK and one MAP_GUARD. The STACK region growns down and gets allocated on demand. If the stack limit is exceeded a segfault will result.
